# Python check if microphone input is muted

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean, microphone

As the title states, is there a way to check if the microphone is muted or not with Python?
I'm making a Microphone toggle script and I want to check if it's on or off.

Here's the script for the toggle if it helps.

```
import win32api
import win32gui
WM_APPCOMMAND = 0x319
APPCOMMAND_MICROPHONE_VOLUME_MUTE = 0x180000

hwnd_active = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
win32api.SendMessage(hwnd_active, WM_APPCOMMAND, None, APPCOMMAND_MICROPHONE_VOLUME_MUTE)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this site help [Microphone Settings](https://python-hangout-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/Microphone.html)

Comment: @itprorh66 quoting the docs "**Hangout API is python API for for controlling Google Hangouts video calls built on top of selenium library**". This does not tell you if the microphone is muted globally in the system but in google hangouts.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? I'm looking now and can't find anything helpful online, just a bunch of reposted questions in Chinese forums without an answer